# How to add a column like a sum() of another columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

```
id|Type | Value
--------------
1 |Type1|Value1
2 |Type1|Value2
3 |Type1|Value3
4 |Type2|Value4
```

and I would like to get another column with a value equal to sum() of the values of the same types of Type column. 
Like that:

```
id|Type | Value | Total
-----------------------
1 |Type1|Value1 |Value1+Value2+Value3
2 |Type1|Value2 |Value1+Value2+Value3
3 |Type1|Value3 |Value1+Value2+Value3
4 |Type2|Value4 |Value4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an excellent use case for [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html). Use `sum() over (partition by ...)`:

```
select id, type, value, sum(value) over (partition by type)
from table1;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c81f3/1)

Sample data:

```
| id |  type | value |
|----|-------|-------|
|  1 | Type1 |     1 |
|  2 | Type1 |     2 |
|  3 | Type1 |     3 |
|  4 | Type2 |     4 |
```

gives sample result:

```
| id |  type | value | sum |
|----|-------|-------|-----|
|  1 | Type1 |     1 |   6 |
|  2 | Type1 |     2 |   6 |
|  3 | Type1 |     3 |   6 |
|  4 | Type2 |     4 |   4 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `GROUP BY` clause for this purpose like

```
select t1.id, t1.Type, t1.Value, xxx.Total
from table1 t1 join
(
select Type, sum(Value) as Total
from table1
group by Type
) xxx on t1.Type = xxx.Type;
```

Comment: @jpw, `Type` may not be unique and so joining would result undesired result in that case. So, need to choose the column with unique data like `id` in this case.

Comment: @jpw, Thanks, didn't see that it's tagged with `Postgresql`; in a impression that it's `Mysql`. Make sense.